Worker calls the function multiple times
I am trying to show a local notification in the scheduled days of week, in the scheduled hour and minute even if the app is killed.
The reason I am not using Alarm Manager is because the Android 14 only supports the USE_EXACT_ALARM permission, but google play does not support it if you are not using calendar. Since I am not using calendar i am trying a different way to show the notification. The problem is, if i use the Worker, since it does a lot of calls all the time, the notification shows more than 40 times.I want to show the notification only once, i tried using the preferences but again the notification will show 4 times. Here is my code, if I set the seconds also to 0, the notification will not show at all. I don't know how to fix this issue, when the seconds are 0 the worker does not catch the time, but if i remove it, it will show 40+ times the notification. I am confused, how can i fix this
class ReminderWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        if(AppPreferences.userNotifications && AppPreferences.specialUserNotifications){
            AppPreferences.selectedDays.fromPrettyJson<ArrayList<String>>().forEach {
                val nextNotificationTime =calculateInitialDelay(
                    it.toInt(),
                    AppPreferences.hourOfDay,
                    AppPreferences.minuteOfDay
                )

                if (nextNotificationTime == 0L) {
                    triggerNotification()
                }
                else {
                   scheduleNextWork(nextNotificationTime)
                }
            }
        }
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun calculateInitialDelay(dayOfWeek: Int, hourOfTheDay: Int, minuteOfTheDay: Int): Long {
        val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
//            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//            set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        }

        val notificationCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek)
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfTheDay)

//If i set the seconds 0 here the notification will not come
//            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//            set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        }
        var initialDelay = notificationCalendar.timeInMillis - currentCalendar.timeInMillis
        if (initialDelay < 0) {
            notificationCalendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1)
            initialDelay = notificationCalendar.timeInMillis - currentCalendar.timeInMillis
        } else if (initialDelay == 0L) {
            // If the scheduled time is exactly now
             return 0L
        }
        return initialDelay
    }


    private fun scheduleNextWork(nextNotificationTime: Long) {
        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>()
            .setInitialDelay(nextNotificationTime - System.currentTimeMillis(), java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(workRequest)
    }

    private fun triggerNotification() {
        val notificationId = Random().nextInt(60000)

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId = applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        // Create the NotificationChannel
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val descriptionText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
                enableLights(true)
                enableVibration(true)

                if (defaultSoundUri != null) {
                    val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build()
                    setSound(defaultSoundUri, att)
                }

                lightColor = Color.parseColor("#501450")
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val newIntent = Intent(applicationContext, StartActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        newIntent.action = "actionString" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            0,
            newIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#222831"))
            .setContentText(applicationContext.getString(R.string.remiderNotificationText))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(LongArray(0))
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}

